# Rest Easy Client 3.0.10 with tomcat 8 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.close()V

Tags: java, resteasy

I am developing rest service using ReastEasy 3.0.10 API with tomcat 8 and jAVA 8. My code is working fine on window machine but when I deployed WAR file on Linux machine, It gives error `org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.close()V`

The no of jar files are same as it is on local. I am having two jar files `javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1` and `jaxrs-api-3.0.10.Final` in my lib folder. Both are having Response class and close method. But Still it is giving error on Linux server. Any suggestion?

The client code is

```
try {
            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            String targetUrl = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/appname/rest/resturl"

            WebTarget target = client.target(targetUrl);

            response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header("AUTHENTICATED", true)
                    .post(Entity.entity(RestUtil.convertObjectToJSONString(object), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            responseString = response.readEntity(String.class);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
```

Also I have noticed one thing, It calls the rest service and print data which rest is returning but After that it prints Internal Server Error 500 in log before printing above mentioned error.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved it by excluding the below.

```
    <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After investing one day finally I found that this error comes when some other jar having same class with same package structure. I used a tool [JARMINATOR](http://jarminator.sourceforge.net/) to scan all of my jar files. Now I have fixed this issue but still it is a question why window machine was not loading that jar but linux machine was loading into Linux machine.

Comment: You can always ask you build enviiornment to generate a build tree, if you use `maven` the following command will tell you which jar is causing the problem.

`mvn dependency:tree`

As to why its different on `Linux` and `Windows`, again it  will be down to your build environment/tools